# Sending Images Using React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to  add sending images  feature in my  react native mobile application using base64. Is  tha essential thing to use following all prameters when use base64 ?**fs.writeFile(`./uploads/${req.body.imageName}.${req.body.imageExt}`, binaryData, err =**

```
 //const Order = require("../models/image.model.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fs = require('fs')

exports.submit = (req, res) => {
  const binaryData = new Buffer(req.body.image, 'base64');

  fs.writeFile(`./uploads/${req.body.imageName}.${req.body.imageExt}`, binaryData, err => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "Couldn't upload"
      })
    } else {
      // Image saved

      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Success"
      })

      /*
      Use GCP bucket
      Upload -> callback -> fetchUrl
      */
    }
  })
};
```